# How to add optional parameters to C#-Method

Tags: c#, parameters, optional-parameters

I have a method which searches for employees. This method got a lot of optional parameters as search-parameters. My Api is used in many single programs in our system and i want to add two new optional parameter to it. If iam doing so compiler is fine, but the using programs of my api are getting Method missing exceptions. Ok i understand that so far, because intern the old Method isnt longer existing (parameterlist is different). Now i thought i easily can overload it. But now the compiler can't different my two methods (old and overload) for sure.

Small example:

Old-Version:

```
public virtual List<IEmployee> Search(int? personalNr = null, bool? active = null, DateTime? dateOfBirth = null)
```

Needed-Version:

```
public virtual List<IEmployee> Search(int? personalNr = null, bool? active = null, DateTime? dateOfBirth = null, string firstName = null, string lastName = null)
```

Just want to add two parameters. I know i can compile all using dll, but this API is used massive and i don't want to transfer all dll's on Live-System.

Is there a common way how to handle this situation?

**CLARIFY**

1.
I just add two new optional parameters to the existing method to extend it:
All calling programs getting Missing-Method Exception because the signature changed.

2.
I overload the method. Now the compiler can't differ the overload and the method. This i quite clear to me. Someone could call `Search(active: true);` which method should .Net take?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan If i extend the method with 2 Parameters i dont get any error. Just if i start a program which uses my api. If i overload iam getting error at compile-time

Comment: @Sebi Can't you change it like `Search(int? personalNr = null, bool? active = null, DateTime? dateOfBirth = null, string firstName = null, string lastName = null)`? `dateOfBirth` is already nullable. This would fit both scenarios as far as I can see...

Comment: @Prix This will follow in Missing-Method Exceptions in all calling programs as described above. Would need to compile and transfer all programs.

Comment: @Sebi do you have the call declared on an interface or elsewhere to restrict it to `DateTime? dateOfBirth`? Honestly I don't even know how you're compiling your first piece of code given that it would result on an error `Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters`.

Comment: You'll have to compile both the assembly with this method, and the assemblies that use the method.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko you could encapsulate the first method to use your custom method which should work... I overlooked that possibility in your answer tough not sure it would be the best way...

Comment: Also read: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/08/10/versioning-issues-with-optional-arguments.aspx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thank you guys for response. My problem is that i don't want to effect the programs outside. So i decided to create a new class `SearchParams`. This holds all parameters listed. So i can overload my existing method and pass `SearchParams` as parameter. I will set old method `Obsolete`. The SearchParams class is free extendable then.

Changes:

Create new class like this:

```
public class SearchParams
{
  public int? PersonalNr{get;set;}
  public bool? Active {get;set;}
  public DateTime? DateOfBirth{get;set}
  public string FirstName{get;set;}
  public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

Overload Search-Method:

```
public List<IEmployee> Search(SearchParams paramList)
```

So the caller first creates the parameter and pass this to the search.
In my opinion this seems to be the best way.

Comment: pretty much @DmitryBychenko 's answer

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the best way to do it is :

- declare a private method that need all the parameters and which manage the emptyness (or not)  of each parameters.
- declare one public method for each number of parameters possible
- each public method call the private method converting missing parameters to empty parameters.

From my point of view i don't think using optionnal paremeters is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

This is **another** suggestion.

You can remove `optional` parameters from the old method. Make all parameters mandatory.

```
    public virtual List<object> Search(int? personalNr, bool? active, DateTime? dateOfBirth)
    {
    }
```

Then make all parameters `optional` in your second method.

```
    public virtual List<object> Search(int? personalNr = null, bool? active = null, DateTime? dateOfBirth = null, string firstName = null, string lastName = null)
    {
    }
```

Now suppose you are calling this method like this;

```
 Search(1,true, DateTime.Now);
```

The above will execute your old method.

```
 Search(1,true, DateTime.Now, null);
```

This will execute your new method.

However, if I was in your position, I would have just renamed the old method.

Comment: Can the person who down voted explain the reason behind it?

Answer (score -1):

The problem may come from the position of your optional parameters.
It seems that it is compiling "for some reason" but that should not be working.

As a workaround, you should modify your needed version :

```
public virtual List<IEmployee> Search(int? personalNr = null, bool? active = null, DateTime? dateOfBirth, string firstName = null, string lastName = null)
```

Leave the old method as well but move the code from your "basic" version to the overloaded one. And when the "basic" search is called, just call your search method and fit the firstName and the lastName as null parameters.

EDIT: Just saw your edit, my post does not make much sense then :)

Comment: This won't work. As described i can't overload the method. Because the compiler can't differ the methods. This is quite clear. Read my Questions clarification.

Comment: Yeah I know, it was added while I was typing I suppose